# ARKit – Image recognition with similar images but different colors

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I have a 2D marker that has a color scheme of red. I used ARKit's ARReferenceImage to detect images via rear camera.
I'm having problems with the marker because it detects similar images but in different color scheme, I think ARKit recognizes only the pattern and disregarding the color.

I already implemented the basic code for image recognition from [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/detecting_images_in_an_ar_experience)

What my goal is to avoid detecting similar markers in different color schemes, I tried to search around but no luck. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To recognize similar images with different colour scheme in ARKit or in RealityKit is a bad idea from the very beginning.

- At first, please take into consideration that ARReferenceImage is a set. Swift's set is unordered collection of **`UNIQUE`** values. If Apple engineers wanted to create ARReferenceImage as array they would do it. But it's a `SET` in every sense of this word – in images' names and visually.

  ```
   func referenceImages(inGroupNamed name: String, 
                                   bundle: Bundle?) -> Set<ARReferenceImage>?
  ```

- Secondly, when implementing ARTrackable protocol (remember, `ARImageAnchor` conforms to `ARTrackable`), you shouldn't track similar images or repetitive structures as Apple suggests.

  ```
   @available(iOS 11.3, *)
   open class ARImageAnchor : ARAnchor, ARTrackable {

       open var referenceImage: ARReferenceImage { get }

       @available(iOS 13.0, *)
       open var estimatedScaleFactor: CGFloat { get }
   }
  ```

  Watch [ARKit WWDC 2018 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/602/) (Time 37:40) for details.

- Thirdly, iPhone's neural engine perceives ARKit's and RealityKit's reference images in the black-and-white spectrum. I think it's made for two main reasons: one – Luma-contrast is more important than Chroma-contrast, and second – image recognition doesn't depend on environment light color – whether it's yellowish or blueish – the recognition's result should be unaltered.

  Do you guess what ARKit sees, looking at three similar images with different colour scheme?

[image]

The differences between green and cyan images are subtle.

Comment: Oh thank you @Andy, so there's no other way for me to achieve my goal using ARKit?

Comment: I think there's no robust way.